# Improvement and parallelization of a code that produces combinations of specified string characters

Tags: r, parallel-processing, combinations

First of all let me try explain you what the following code is doing.

From a list like the above it takes the containing string `"1MAKK"` and tries to find the possible combinations of the positions of the specified characters at `chars`

Here is an example of the initial conformation

```
# Initial list
lst1 = list("P1"=list("1MAKK") )
chars = c("M","K")
classes = c("class.1","class.35")
# Get the P name
p_name = names(lst1[1])
# Get the string sequence
p_seq = unlist(lst1[[1]][1])
```

The `classes` list is nothing more than some labels corresponding to the `chars` list and just used for some naming.

Now the main code is getting these variables `p_name , p_seq` and produces a data frame with all possible combinations of the position combinations of the specified characters.

This is the code:

```
library(stringr)          # str_locate
library(purrr)            # map2

# Functions
move_one <- function(seq){
  if(grepl("1" , seq))
    seq = paste0(substring(seq,2),1)
  else
    seq
}

# Move the number one from the first to last position
seq = move_one(p_seq)

# Get the positions of each character in the string
pos = unlist( map2( 
  .f=function(a ,p) str_locate_all(p, a) , 
  .x=chars , 
  .y=seq), 
  recursive = F
  )
# Check if there is a letter that didn't exist in the sequence and add zeros at the respective list item
for( x in 1:length(pos)){
  ifelse(is.na(pos[[x]][1]) , pos[[x]] <- rbind(pos[[x]] , c(0,0)) , pos[[x]] <- pos[[x]] )
}

# Calculate all possible combinations and transpose the arrays inside the list
ind1 = pmap( 
  .f = function(x) lapply(1:nrow(pos[[x]]), combn, x=as.list(pos[[x]][,1])), 
  .l = list( 1:length(pos) )  
  )

ind1 = pmap( 
  .f = function(x) lapply(ind1[[x]], t) , 
  .l = list( 1:length(ind1) )
  )

# Add Zero at each first element
z = pmap( 
  .f = function(x) lapply(ind1[[x]][1] , rbind , 0 ) , 
  .l = list( 1:length(ind1) )
  )
# Merge the list with the zeros and the complete one
ind1 = map2(
  .f = function(a,b) {a[1]<-b[1]; a},
  .x = ind1,
  .y = z)
# Create a vector for each letter combination
ind1 = pmap( 
  .f = function (x) unlist( lapply(ind1[[x]], function(i) do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(i), sep = ':'))) ), 
  .l = list ( 1:length(ind1) )
  )

# Get the position of the class.1
isClass1 = grep("class.1", classes)
# Check if the seq is the first one
isFirst = grepl("1",seq)

# Set only 1 and 0 in the vector of UNIMOD.1 if is the first peptide
ifelse(isFirst , ind1[[isClass1]] <- c("1","0") , ind1[[isClass1]] <- c("0") ) 
# expand.grid for all these vectors inside ind1
ind2 = expand.grid(ind1)

# Apply column names in ind2
colnames(ind2) = classes
# Add a column with the p_name and seq
ind3 = cbind( "p_name"=rep(p_name, nrow(ind2) ) , "seq"=rep( gsub('.{1}$','',seq) , nrow(ind2) )  , ind2 )
```

The result for that specific input will be

```
> ind3
  p_name  seq  class.1  class.35
1     P1 MAKK        1         3
2     P1 MAKK        0         3
3     P1 MAKK        1         4
4     P1 MAKK        0         4
5     P1 MAKK        1         0
6     P1 MAKK        0         0
7     P1 MAKK        1       3:4
8     P1 MAKK        0       3:4
```

As you can see I tried to use lapply, map2,pmap methods and not for loops in order to make it faster and to give it a chance to run in more than one CPU core in the final version.

So somewhere here is where I need your help and your opinion.

The actual initial list of mine does not have only one string character but it looks like the following one, but with the difference that there are thousands of inner lists (Px where x = {1,2,3,4,...2000} and each Px could have around a hundred of sequences.

```
p_list = list( "P1" = list( c("1MAK","ERTD","FTRWDSE" )) , "P2" = list( c("1MERTDF","DFRGRSDFG","DFFF")) )
```

The first question and probably the easiest one to answer, is how can I run (apply) the above code in such a list.

And secondly how can I implement this to be calculated in parallel and use more than one of CPU cores from a server that has 24 of them in order to save some time.

P.S: The final result expected to be the combination of all the individual results (using rbind maybe), (like the one previously showed) into a data frame.

Any improvement, idea or suggestion is welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: what is `move_one` and `a.a`? can you explain?

Comment: Oops sorry. `a.a` is a typo and changed it to `chars` while `move_one()` is just a function that takes the number one if exists from the first position of the sequence and paste it to the last. ( I also post its code )

Comment: `chars` will be only letters? not words?

Comment: Yup. Chars can only be letters.

Comment: sorry but its very had to get into your process, because you are using  a lot of `map` and `apply ` functions, which in my opinion is unnecessary. You should first write simple function that processes one word (as fast as it can be done), and then it would be easy to apply it on list), but your current approach is too complicated. (and definitely would be slow)

Comment: That's exactly what I tried to do. Before the above code, I had around 300 lines of code (for ,if etc) doing the same thing and I decided to make it more small and efficient. What's confusing you? Do you want to explain the code line by line in the comments or send you an email ? What if you see and write the whole code above as a function ( I mean inside function(arguments) state) ? Would it be more helpful then to apply it on the list ? Thank you very much though for your time .

Comment: What is the goal of putting the `1` at the end?

Comment: To identify that this is the first sequence in the list. And if it's in the first position, then it changes the position of the characters after it. i.e in the 1MAK , M is in the 2nd position while in the MAK1 , M is in the first as expected.

Answer (score 1):

### First part

This is basically the code I would use for one string. At the end, you get column-lists (which is nice is you know what it is).

```
library(purrr)
x <- "MAKK"
chars <- set_names(c("M", "K"), c("class.1", "class.35"))

get_0_and_all_combn <- function(x) {
  map(seq_along(x), function(i) combn(x, i, simplify = FALSE)) %>%
    unlist(recursive = FALSE) %>%
    c(0L, .)
}
get_0_and_all_combn(3:4)
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 4

[[4]]
[1] 3 4

get_pos_combn <- function(x, chars) {
  x.spl <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]] 
  map(chars, function(chr) {
    which(x.spl == chr) %>%
      get_0_and_all_combn()
  }) %>%
    expand.grid()
}
get_pos_combn(x, chars)
  class.1 class.35
1       0        0
2       1        0
3       0        3
4       1        3
5       0        4
6       1        4
7       0     3, 4
8       1     3, 4

get_pos_combn_with_infos <- function(seq, chars, p_name) {
  cbind.data.frame(p_name, seq, get_pos_combn(seq, chars))
}
get_pos_combn_with_infos(x, chars, p_name)
  p_name  seq class.1 class.35
1     P1 MAKK       0        0
2     P1 MAKK       1        0
3     P1 MAKK       0        3
4     P1 MAKK       1        3
5     P1 MAKK       0        4
6     P1 MAKK       1        4
7     P1 MAKK       0     3, 4
8     P1 MAKK       1     3, 4
```

---

So, now if you want me to finish my answer, I would need to know which are the `chars` and `classes` corresponding to your complete example

```
p_list = list( "P1" = list( c("1MAK","ERTD","FTRWDSE" )) , 
               "P2" = list( c("1MERTDF","DFRGRSDFG","DFFF")) )
```

Also, are you sure you want to make "P1" and "P2" lists of length 1?

Comment: Because my comment was a little big I posted to pastebin (https://pastebin.com/YvSciXZs) . Thank you for your interest.

Comment: There are too many requirements in your question. This is impossible to follow.

Comment: I understand. Thank you anyway  for your help and your time :)